# Selecting rows in dataframe where a value is larger than the categorical mean

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I'm trying to find employees that have higher salaries above the average departmental salary, but I'm having a bit of trouble in Pandas.

In SQL, my query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT name, department, salary
FROM employees e1
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employees e2 WHERE e1.department = e2.department)
```

Here is my attempt in Pandas:

```py
df.groupby(['Department']).filter(lambda x: df['salary'] > x.salary.mean())[['Name', 'Salary']]
```

I get the following error which I am assuming is coming from df['salary'] in my filter clause:

> filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool

Comment: `df.loc[df["Salary"]>df.groupby("Department")["Salary"].transform("mean")]`?

Answer (score 1):

this is not as readable as i would like but i think it works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['employees', 'department', 'salary', 'other_features'],
      data=[['A', 'C1', 1300, 5], 
            ['B', 'C1', 1250, 10], 
            ['C', 'C1', 2000, 18],
            ['D', 'C3', 1240, 21], 
            ['E', 'C1', 1700, 29],
            ['F', 'C2', 1550, 11],
            ['G', 'C3', 2100, 2],
            ['H', 'C3', 1090, 7],
            ['I', 'C2', 1400, 13],
            ['B', 'C2', 1100, 4]])



df.set_index('employees').groupby('department').apply(lambda x: x[x.salary > x.salary.mean()])['salary']

output:

             employees  salary
department          
C1             C         2000
               E         1700
C2             F         1550
               I         1400
C3             G         2100
```